# TypeScript не дает использовать onclick

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть функция в скрипте которая должна выводить некоторый текст при нажатии кнопки.

**TS:**

```
    function asd(){
        console.log('asd');
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="text">
   <div class="price">99.000</div>
   <div class="productName">REVO Morning</div>
   <div class="inf">đắng, hậu ngọt, hương hoa </div>
   <div class="cart-btn">
     <button class="in__cart" onclick="asd()">MUA NGAY</button>
     <a href="" class="deetails">CHI TIẾT</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Но при использовании TS он выдаёт ошибку что данная функция не найдена.

При использовании **TS**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании **JS**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот как это исправить и почему так происходит? Помогите пожалуйста

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pypochek/wcun8yo1/2/)

P.s. В самом проекте больше таких "табличек" с такими кнопками.

---

В комментариях к моему вопросу два человека мне очень помогли, за что я их и благодарю.

Comment: Так TS по умолчанию работает как модуль, а не вываливает  функцию в глобальный scope

Comment: В явном виде их глобальными можете сделать `window.asd = function.....`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь